# Delete playlist video youtube api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to empty a playlist using java-script, I have managed to get all the playlist video ids but not able to delete them

```
function getVids() {
    $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
        part: 'id',
        maxResults: 50,
        playlistId: 'PLPVr3MCINEgGAg9ThKr7sLMwqFNM9Iv4L',
    key: 'my key here'},
    function(data){
        var output = 0;
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
            //console.log(item);
            //console.log(item.id);
        $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&id="+item.id+"&key=my key here",
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
    alert('s');
     }
   });
  })
 })
};
```

When i enter the url into browser this is what returns

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/YAyqaxa-qQcwBUIplqskG6cfrsw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
"items": [
 {
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/iMYbauGN6REXTfoVQ6B49q5YvcQ\"",
 "id":     "UExQVnIzTUNJTkVnR0FnOVRoS3I3c0xNd3FGTk05SXY0TC4zRjM0MkVCRTg0MkYyQTM0"
  }
 ]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Got it working, instead of using my api key I had to use a access token (Thanks @DalmTo)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=id&id="+item.id+"&access_token="+accesstoken,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
         }
```

Comment: change key to access_token for starters key is used for public api keys your going to need a access token to delete stuff.

Comment: @DaImTo I have now to got a refresh and access token, how do I implement these?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you, got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional to DaImTo answer, by using the [`PlaylistItems: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), you can get here all the videos inside that Playlist. Note that this list of videos has individual **"id"**.

Here is the example response of PlaylistItems: list.

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/xn3GV......MlvYumGPB2BTU\"",
   "id": "UExnVEMxxx....",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-09-29T11:53:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCTEAr....SLNZ0tBIw2w",
    "title": "Kobe Bryant's All Game Winners of his Career (36)",
```

Now, you can delete this specific video in your Playlist by using the [`PlaylistItems: delete`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete) by indicating the **"id"** that you get.

In our example we get the "id" **UExnVEMxxx....**, so this id is the one that you need to use in PlaylistItems: delete.

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?id=UExnVEMxxx....&key={YOUR_API_KEY}